# Square Brackets in a hyperlink aem

Tags: aem, richtext

I need to use square brackets in my link in Richtext hyperlink.
Like
[https://stackoverflow.com?employeeId=[[Employee_ID]]](https://stackoverflow.com?employeeId=%5B%5BEmployee_ID%5D%5D)

When I pass this as a link, it removes the href and I get output as
 Link

Comment: Can you please describe your problem a bit in detail. Also, if there is a sightly code which you have written for this, can you please paste that as well?

Comment: I am using OOTB /libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext rte plugins links in my component, when I am authoring a link which has square brackets in it, href is not getting generated. “<a target=“_blank”> Link </a>”. In logs I can see AntiSamy warning by class org.apache.sling.xss.impl.HtmlToHtmlContentContext class- The href attribute has been filtered out, but the tag is in place.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to overlay the AntiSamy configuration, you should copy it to `/apps/cq/xssprotection/config.xml` and add the proper rules to allow the brackets.